# No spaces between tokens in ANTLR

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I'm writing a very simple subset of a C# grammar as an exercise.

However, I have a rule which whitespaces are giving me some troubles.

I want to distinguish the following:

```
int a;
int? b;
```

Where the the first is a "regular" int type and the second is a nullable int type.

However, with my current grammar I'm not being able to parse this.

```
type     : typeBase x='?'    -> { x == null } typeBase
                             -> ^('?' typeBase)
         ;

typeBase : 'int'
         | 'float'
         ;
```

The thing is that whith these rules, it only works with a whitespace before '?', like this:

```
int ? a;
```

Which I'd don't want.

Any ideas?

Comment: The rewrite rule in `type` is incorrect: you have two rewrite rules where there should be one. Also, shouldn't this `'?'` be optional? Right now, it must always contain a `'?'`.

Comment: Anyway, without the rewrite rules, both `int?` and `int ?` are parsed properly.

Answer (score 2):

1) Your definition of whitespace seems to be flawed ... the grammar you present should accept "int?" and "int ?". Maybe you should take a look of the definition of whitespace.

2) If you want to disallow "int ? a" you can define extra tokens 'int?' and 'float?' ... normally you allow whitespace to appear between every token, so you have to make it one token.

Comment: Yeah, defining extra tokens like `int?`, `float?` etc. would be the way to go if spaces are not allowed between the type and the question mark. And #1 is correct: both `int?` and `int ?` are accepted by the generated parser.